# How to fetch only CH_PAY_MODE loan_id from this table?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

| loan_id | coll_date | coll_pay_mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8007571771 | APR-2022 | CH |
| 8007571771 | FEB-2022 | CH |
| 8007571771 | JAN-2022 | CH |
| 8007571771 | MAR-2022 | CH |
| 8007571771 | MAR-2022 | CL |
| 8007571771 | MAY-2022 | CH |
| 8007636540 | APR-2022 | CH |
| 8007636540 | JAN-2022 | CH |
| 8007636540 | MAR-2022 | CH |
| 8007636540 | MAY-2022 | CH |

For the data above, there is two `loan_id` given in the table, per month collection using `CH` or `CL`, so i wanted to fetch `loan_id` which is not paying in `CL` in any month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the method to achieve your desired result is to use EXISTS clause -

```
SELECT DISTINCT loan_id
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
 WHERE coll_pay_mode = 'CH'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
                   WHERE T1.loan_id = t2.loan_id
                     AND T2.coll_pay_mode = 'CL')
```

Comment: @RanvirChauhan, Always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

One option in to use conditional aggregation along with HAVING clause such as

```sql
SELECT loan_id
  FROM t
 GROUP BY loan_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN coll_pay_mode = 'CL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `LEFT JOIN` as well:

```
SELECT distinct loan_id
FROM yourtable t1
LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
ON loan_id = t2.loan_id and
   t2.col1_pay_mode = 'CL'
WHERE t1.col1_pay_mode = 'CH' AND
      t2.col1_pay_mode IS NULL;
```

So, we do a self left-join to make sure that there is no `t2` match to `t1` with `col1_pay_mode` being CL and we select `distinct` values.